# background image not appearing in table cell

Tags: html, css

I am unable to add a background image in a table cell. The background image just never appears.

I tried:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center-on-narrow" role="presentation" style="display:table !important;" mc:edit="imagewithcta">
                <tr>
                  <td class="button-td" background="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
                    <a class="button-a sans text-white" href="*|ARCHIVE3|*">
                      <span class="button-link">
                        READ MORE
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

and

```html
  <table class="center-on-narrow" style="display: table !important;" role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="button-td" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');"><a class="button-a sans text-white" href="*|ARCHIVE3|*"> <span class="button-link"> READ MORE </span> </a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**UPDATE**

FYI I did not write it as table format, I am just helping a client with this pre-written code. Below is an image that shows a read more button and they require a background image behind it:

[image]

Comment: Is `background` even an attribute in [td](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. (But don't use tables for layout. CSS came along in the 1990s)

Comment: background-image showing. If you set 'background-size: cover;', I this you understand what it happens.

Comment: You just need to give your <td> some height and width, with 'background-size: cover;'. This will solve your problem. Also try to use CSS to have more control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background is being applied to the table cell, you just can't see it. If you change the width and height of the cell, its evident. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

```html
  <table class="center-on-narrow" style="display: table !important;" role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="button-td" style="display:block;width:700px; height: 700px; background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');"><a class="button-a sans text-white" href="*|ARCHIVE3|*"> <span class="button-link"> READ MORE </span> </a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the size of the `<td>`, you can resize the background, using `background-size: cover`;

Comment: So the code isn't mine to begin with. It was from another developer. The client states she is having issues with images not appearing so I was trying to help her out. It's in mailchimp and the way it was coded I agree, not good in table format

Comment: I'll send a picture in my question above so you can see it

Comment: @BruceyBandit where exactly are you checking on the result? You/your client are aware, that most web mailers/mail clients will _not_ display external images per default (because that would allow tracking of when an email was “opened”), right …?

Comment: @BruceyBandit line 522 of your screen shot of the code is where you need the background applied. on the TR. The table row rather than the cell.

Comment: @CBroe I don't know about this. I don't know much about mailchimp. I was asked to do this as I do some programming with Wordpress but no idea how mail chimp works sorry

Comment: @Squiggs.Thank you, that worked perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

the background image is showing but you can't see it because of height and width.
add

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

and also, add height and width to td tag to show clear.

working code is here
https://codepen.io/haidertoqeer/pen/jOBzEjO